# Derivative on polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $F$ be a ring, let $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_nx^n$ be in $F[x]$, and $f'(x)$ be the regular derivative of $f(x)$.
>
> Prove that $(f+g)'(x)=f'(x)+g'(x)$.
>
> Conclude that we can define a homomorphism of abelian groups $D:F[x]\to F[x]$ by $D(f(x))=f'(x)$.

How to prove that $(fg)'=f'g+fg'$?

Comment: Did you also need help with the problem itself, or were you just wondering about whether you were expected to prove that $F[x]$ is an abelian group?

Comment: I need help on the char part.

Comment: I've added a hint for that part.

Comment: ive solved this problem on a hw. i could send you a pdf of my hw if you want.

Comment: I think one of the main purposes of this site is to post answers here, not to send the hw.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really anything to prove; part of the axioms for a ring are that a ring is an abelian group under addition. If you feel the need to say anything about the issue at all, it should be fine to just say $F[x]$ is abelian group under addition by the ring axioms.

---

*Hint for finding the kernel of $D$ when $F$ is of prime characteristic*

Note that
$$D(x^p)=px^{p-1}=0$$
because $p=0$ in the field $F$. Do you see now which polynomials will have a derivative which equals 0?

Comment: Hello,  does it make any difference if we don't assume $p$ being prime? I mean, the same reasoning holds for any other natural number $p$, right? I'm just asking because I have a homework asking me which is the kernel of $D$ when the characteristic of the ring is a prime number $p$ but it seems to me that it will have the same shape regardless of $p$ being prime or not

Answer (score 0):

The condition that $f'$ does not vanish [is equivalent to $f$ being separable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inseparable_extension#Separable_and_inseparable_polynomials).